# Is it necessary to read signals and systems before statistical signal processing/ detection theory

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling, mathematical-psychology, signal-detection

For one who is interested in computational neuroscience and brain computer interface, in university curriculum (e.g. BCCN Berlin), it requires a course in statistical signal processing / signal detection theory.

In order to study these, is it strongly necessary to firstly read signals and systems (e.g. Oppenheim Signals and Systems, and, Discrete-Time Digital Signal Processing, in total 2000 pages though..), or it is just ok to directly start with

e.g. Kay, Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing

since in some university course pages, it seems the prerequisite does not include signals and systems.

Comment: "Read" is kind of a loaded term here.  Should you understand every last drop of it?  No.  Are the fundamentals critical for moving on to the deeper material (and Kay is very intense)?  Yes.  The best approach in these cases is to know where to refer back to when you get stuck on something in the advanced text.